# echo is different when sed output is assigned to variable from file

Tags: file, bash, shell, sed, echo

I'm writing a shell script that splits line of string based on a pattern using sed.

```
    #pattern 'string1','string2','string3'

    cat $FILENAME | while read LINE
    do

    firstPart=$(echo "$LINE" | sed -r "s/'(.*)','(.*)','(.*)'/\1/" )
    secondPart=$(echo "$LINE" | sed -r "s/'(.*)','(.*)','(.*)'/\2/" )
    thirdPart=$(echo "$LINE" | sed -r "s/'(.*)','(.*)','(.*)'/\3/" )

    done
```

I am able to print them using individual echos, but if I put them in a single echo as show below

```
    #if LINE from FILE is '123','abc','hello'

    echo "$firstPart $secondPart"
    #this prints " abc" instead of "123 abc"

    #try appending a string on echo
    echo "$firstPart -"
    #this prints " -3" instead of "123 -"
```

When i tried using sed in a constant string in the code, echo seems fine.

```
    #Correct Echo
    SOMESTRING='123','abc','hello'

    firstPart=$(echo "$SOMESTRING" | sed -r "s/'(.*)','(.*)','(.*)'/\1/" )
    secondPart=$(echo "$SOMESTRING" | sed -r "s/'(.*)','(.*)','(.*)'/\2/" )
    thirdPart=$(echo "$SOMESTRING" | sed -r "s/'(.*)','(.*)','(.*)'/\3/" )

    echo "$firstPart $secondPart"
    #this prints "123 abc"
```

Is it the correct behavior of sed when input is a LINE from FILE? how can i make it behave as if the LINE is included and declared in the code(like my second example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you have carriage returns (sometimes written `\r`) embedded in your strings. So when you do `echo "$firstPart -"`, where firstPart="123\r", it prints two lines:

```
123
 -
```

...with the second "line" printed on top of (and overwriting) the first. My guess is that you've edited the script with a text editor that uses DOS-style line endings (i.e. each line ends with carriage return followed by linefeed), but the shell expects unix-style line endings (just linefeed) and treats the carriage return as part of the command (e.g. `firstPart=$(echo "$SOMESTRING" | sed -r "s/'(.*)','(.*)','(.*)'/\1/" )\r`, which will include the `\r` in firstPart.

If this is the problem, running dos2unix on your script should fix it (and then switch to an editor that doesn't use DOS-style line endings).

Comment: if the carriage return is in the middle of the line, dos2unix won't help. You'd need `tr -d '\r'`

Answer (score 0):

When you say `SOMESTRING='123','abc','hello'` to bash, it strips of the single quotes:

```
$ echo "$SOMESTRING"
123,abc,hello
```

If you want to keep them you need to say `SOMESTRING="'123','abc','hello'"`.

This means that your sed patterns are not going work, e.g. `firstPart` is set to the empty string. If you remove the single quotes from the sed pattern it works.

I would however suggest using `IFS` to split up simple delimited input:

```
echo "'123','abc','hello'" | while IFS=, read a b c; do
  echo $a
  echo $b
  echo $c
done
```

Or briefer:

```
while IFS=, read a b c; do echo -e "$a\n$b\n$c"; done <<< "'123','abc','hello'"
```

Output:

```
'123'
'abc'
'hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert, but I can tell this much that when you are piping the "while" script, the variables used within the while are not available in the main script.

Ex: 
If you use the echo statements within the while loop, its shows the parsing by the SED is fine.

You can alternatively use the following syntax to expose these variables in the main script.

```
while read LINE
do

firstPart=$(echo "$LINE" | sed -r "s/'(.*)','(.*)','(.*)'/\1/" )
secondPart=$(echo "$LINE" | sed -r "s/'(.*)','(.*)','(.*)'/\2/" )
thirdPart=$(echo "$LINE" | sed -r "s/'(.*)','(.*)','(.*)'/\3/" )
done < $FILENAME
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SOMESTRING='123','abc','hello'

firstPart=$(echo "$SOMESTRING" | sed "s/\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\)/\1/" )
secondPart=$(echo "$SOMESTRING" | sed "s/\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\)/\2/" )
thirdPart=$(echo "$SOMESTRING" | sed "s/\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\)/\3/" )
```

Comment: Please, try to explain what your code does and why it solves the problem, thanks!